# Annotations is not saving in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, annotations

In my project I'm working on annotation for pdf file. In this example [LazyPDFKit](https://github.com/lazyprogram/LazyPDFKit) bookmark and annotation are working  good, but if I change the Pdf file it shows same Annotation only. How can I save a different Annotation?